# html5 offline cache is caching all files instead of cached files that are listed

Tags: html5-appcache

I am trying to use offline caching of html5. But problem is it is caching all html files and not the ones I mentioned in cache manifest file:
For ex: I have 4 html files: index.html, test.html, sample.html, fallback.html and I have sample.appcache manifest file that contains:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
sample.html
NETWORK:
test.html
FALLBACK:
/ /fallback.html
```

I dont have manifest="sample.appcache" attribute set in any html file. I am using JBoss 5 AS and in web.xml I added mime mappings as follows:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>appcache</extension>
    <mime-type>text/cache-manifest</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

So only index.html and sample.html needs to be cached offline but test.html is also getting cached if it was hit earlier when server was up. The fallback.html is not getting called when server is stopped in place of this test.html
What is wrong with this setup?
Second thing I did not understand is on IE(v9) and Firefox(v19) I don't have to set mime-mappings but for application to work on chrome(v26) and safari(v5.1.7) this setting is indeed mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked with JBoss, but the reason that Chrome and Safari want the MIME type for the appcache is because otherwise it has no way of identifying it as an cache manifest.  Simple solution is to just include it :-P

As for the caching, where are you seeing it cached?  Is it for sure being stored in the offline section?  Keep in mind that files will still be cached like normal regardless of the cache manifest.

Comment: After stopping the server, still I'm able to view the pages by hitting the url: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index.html whereas earlier if I don't use manifest file then this page cannot be displayed after server shut down.

Comment: Use the development tools in Chrome (ctrl + shift + I on PC), and there is a tab for resources, which has a small section for viewing where resources are being stored.  Use this is make sure that indeed the files are being stored by the offline manifest cache, and not some other system cache or browser cache.

Comment: Thanks for the hint in chrome. There was error in loading fallback page "/fallback.html" was not correct, it worked by removing slash as in console there was 404 for this page. Also I noticed that for safari /firefox to work offline, doctype in html page needs to be of html 5 only - this was exception for chrome. Now I can see my appcache under Resources-"Application cache" tab in chrome and safari. For IE its still not working. How to debug in IE for application cache is working correctly or not? Also is there plugin in Firefox to view this Application Cache like in chrome?

Comment: I found that as per http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp IE 10 supports application cache and I have IE9 installed. This might be the reason.